# Prevent GridView from resizing when clicking on The LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

How can i prevent my grid from resizing when clicking on the edit link button? i just need my gridview to be fixed..

note that when you click on the edit linkbutton 2 buttons appear : 1 for the update and 1 for the cancel and in the other cells textboxes appear to update the values that's why my grid is resizing.. how can i fix this?

that's my asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="604px" 
        DataKeyNames="id,firstname,lastname,adress,email,telephone,birthday">

        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>

                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox id="Select" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="false"/>
                      <asp:LinkButton  ID="idedit" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="true" runat="server"
                            ToolTip="Edit"  Text="Edit"/>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="selectID" CommandName="Select" CausesValidation="true" runat="server"
                            ToolTip="Select"  Text="Select" />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>

                 <asp:LinkButton  ID="idupdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Update"
                            ToolTip="Update" OnClientClick="javascript:if(!confirm('Are you sure do you want to update this?')){return false;}" />
                        <asp:LinkButton  ID="idcancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"
                            Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="firstname">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="fnmaetxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fnmaetxt" Text="The first name field is required!"/>--%>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfirstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="lastname">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="lnametxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="lnametxt" Text="The last name field is required!"
                                        runat="server" />--%>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lbllastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="adress">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="adresstxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("adress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lbladress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("adress") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="email">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="emtailtxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="emtailtxt" Text="Not a Valid Email Address" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />--%>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 


           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="telephone">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="phonetxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("telephone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="phonetxt" Text="Not a Valid phone number " SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\d{8}"/>--%>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltelephone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("telephone") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 


           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="birthday">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="birthdaytxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("birthday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblbirthday" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("birthday") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

and that's my code on the editing event:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowEditing
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    GridView1.DataSource = x.selectProfile
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

any help would be much appreciated

thank you in advance

Comment: This link seems to be what you are looking for: http://forums.asp.net/t/1115211.aspx/1

Comment: well the link did not help me because my problem is a bit different

Comment: I wasn't sure that's why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer. Could you please, explain a bit better what you are after?

Comment: when i click on the edit link button that is in the grid,this link is replace by two other linkbuttons: update and cancel and the grid becomes editable so that's why my grid is resizing when i click on the edit link button and i need to prevent this resizing issue... did you get what i mean?

Comment: This is what I understood initially. In winforms, you have the option to not allow users to resize the DataGridView at all. From what I read in this link (although not tested it), I understood that this is the equivalent for GridView in ASP.NET, that is, locking the datagrid such that users cannot affect its dimensions at all; isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: i've already tried it and i'm still facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry, no experience on this front and no time now to do some tests; but you should look for this kind of functionality, which should be there: AllowUserToResizeColumns/rows is the name of the boolean flag in Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Size to your linkbutton to avoid gridview resizing

```
<asp:LinkButton  ID="idcancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"  Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" width="100px" />
```

or

Try this code page_load set your gridview

```
gridview.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word")
```